# how to save json byte[] as pdf in php

Tags: php, json, pdf, curl, byte

via curl request i am getting pdf data as jsonEncoded byte[] . I need to create and save this data as pdf.

can you plz help me how to do this in php .

my Curl Code is  -

```
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, 
array( CURLOPT_POST => TRUE, 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => TRUE, 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(    'Content-Type: application/json' ), 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData) )
);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

When I am printing `responseData` , its giving me this as result  -

`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`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting string of data is [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded data. So, to further process it, you need to call `base64_decode( $responseData );`<sup>1</sup>.

If the data is not corrupted, and you save it to a file, you should get a valid PDF file.

For example:

```
$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
// decode the base64 data
$pdfData = base64_decode( $responseData );
// save the decoded data to a PDF file
file_put_contents( '/path/to/file.pdf', $pdfData );
```

The PDF file should now be saved at `/path/to/file.pdf`.

---

<sup>1) See [base64_decode() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).</sup>

Comment: Experience. :) The `/`, `+`, and especially the `==` at the end of the data are dead give-aways, if you've seen base64 more often. If you see base64 data a few more times, you will probably instantly recognize it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the HTTP header like this:

```
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, 
  array( CURLOPT_POST => TRUE, 
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => TRUE, 
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type:application/pdf'), 
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData) )
);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```